# layout.xml in custom module is not working

Tags: module, layout, blocks, magento-1

**My config code**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Urban_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Urban_Module>
    </modules>
<global>
        <helpers>
            <Module>
                <class>Urban_Module_Helper</class>
            </Module>  
        </helpers>
</global>
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <module>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Urban_Module</module>
                    <frontName>module</frontName>
                </args>
            </module>
        </routers>
         <layout>
            <updates>
                <module>
                    <file>module.xml</file>
                </module>
            </updates>
        </layout>      
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**My TestifrontController.php code**

```
<?php
class Urban_Module_TestifrontController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
    $this->loadLayout();      

    $this->renderLayout();
   echo 'hello frontend';

    }
}
```

**My module.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <module_testifront_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="module/module" name="module" template="module/module.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </module_testifront_index>
</layout>
```

This module.xml path i have used is `app/design/frontend/[package]/default/layout/module.xml` . I have the module.phtml file in `app/design/frontend/[package]/default/template/module/module.phtml.`

The controller works when I navigate to `index.php/module/testifront/index` but the layout doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module does not define any blocks, but you use the block type "module/module"

You probably want to replace that with "core/template"

Answer (score 3):

I see you're missing `blocks` node in your config.xml. Add code given below inside `global` node

```
<blocks>
    <module>
        <class>Urban_Module_Block</class>
    </module>  
</blocks>
```

and create block file `Module.php` which will go inside Urban/Module/Block folder.

In case if you're not going to write your own block functions, your can use block type as block `core/template` as suggested by fschmengler.

Module.php code will be like this

```
<?php
class Urban_Module_Block_Module extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
//your code here.
}
```